# Clarification: Every infinite subset of E has a limit point of E iff E is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

Every infinite subset of E has a limit point of E iff E is compact.

Is this always true?

Comment: Do you use that a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded?

Comment: Yes I could use that, but is that even necessary?

Comment: Well, that set cannot be unbounded (otherwise you could find an infinite set without a limit point) and closeness follows along the similar lines.

Comment: Oh I see. So knowing that it is closed and bounded, if I can find a sequence in the cartesian product that converges to some limit point, I can conclude that it is compact?

Comment: your commas confuse me :) A = *knowing that it is closed and bounded if I can find a sequence in the cartesian product that converges to some limit point* implies B = *it is compact*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in the title is false in general: a topological space $X$ that satisfies the condition

> (*) Every infinite subspace $E$ of $X$ has a limit point.

is called limit point compact. And a product of two spaces that are limit point compact need not be limit point compact.

This shows that we cannot rely *only* on this property (*) to show that the product of two compact sets of reals is compact. We need to use more.

E.g. one can use that for metric spaces (like the reals)  property (*), compactness and

> (**) Every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

(which is called sequential compactness) are equivalent. It is quite straightforward to show that the product of two sequentially compact spaces is again sequentially compact (and thus compact, by the equivalence).

For compact subsets of the reals we can also use the compact iff closed and bounded equivalence (which holds for Euclidean spaces, but *not* for all metric spaces, so it's a less general proof). The ease of this proof will depend on whether you already know that the product of closed sets is again closed.

Of course, **any** product of compact sets is compact by Tychonoff's theorem, which is overkill here, but the finite case is not too hard, using the open cover definition.

Comment: very helpful. thank you so much!

Comment: Just to complement @Henno Brandsma's answer, a specific example of a limit point compact (also called countably compact) space is the space of all countable ordinals with the order (open interval) topology. Every infinite sequence would contain a strictly increasing subsequence which will converge to its sup